# SonataAdminBundle - configuration

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have 2 Entities, `Orders` and `OrderItems`.

An order can have many items and this all works fine.

I'm looking at the `SonataAdminBundle` and I have setup the dashboard and the services for both of these Entites.

I have seen in the documentation, that when editing an entity, there are tabs that show/hide other sections. For example on the [demo](http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/dashboard)

Under the `Pages` when editing there is the default details and then 2 tabs `Seo` and `Advanced`

What I'd like to display is the following:

1. Display the Order when editing
2. Have a tab to display the collection of Order Items in a separate tab

I've looked all over, but can't find any docs to show ho to do this

EDIT:

It seems I can do this using

```
->with('Orders')
    ->('id)
->with('Items')
...........
```

Comment: Found the documentation: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#advanced-usage-many-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this...

```
 ->with('Orders')
   ->('id')
 ->end()
 ->with('Items')
   --------
 ->end()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it collapsed you should add this:

```
    ->with('Seo',  array('collapsed' => true))
```